# How to assign values to a list

Tags: python, string, list, python-2.7, loops

The decimal numeral system is composed  of ten digits , which we represent as "0123456789".Write a program that will attribute these values to the given list's elements

```
L = ['f','c','e','a','d','p','z','y','k','m'].
```

For example

```
Input is fff
Output is000
```

Note:The code should not have 'for'!
    input is 'ccc' 
    output is 111
    input is 'eeeee'
    output is 22222

I want to write a code for this program on python notebook(python 2.7)! But I am failing to do so. Please help me!

Comment: Can you please show what code you have tried? Also, please clearly indicate where your code is giving you problems.

Comment: I dont have the code in this laptop!

Answer (score 2):

Use [**`index()`**](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) function:

```
>>> x = 'fff'
>>> print ''.join(str(L.index(el)) for el in x)
000
```